# Why does Err.Description remain empty in Excel / VBA error handling?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am not able to access the error description (or error number) in Excel VBA error handling.
If I run the following code, the error description remains `Empty`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestError()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Debug.Print 1 / 0
    'Alternative: (Does not display error number either):
    'Err.Raise 10000, , "Some error description"

ErrorExit:

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ErrorExit

End Sub
```

[image: Err.Description not available with error handling]

If I replace the `Debug.Print 1 / 0` with an `Err.Raise` statement, the description remains empty as well.
However, if I remove the `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`, the description and error number is shown as expected.

[image: Err.Description without error handler]

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to access the error description? Thank you!

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement

Comment: The `On Error Resume Next` is clearing your error instance, move it to the line AFTER the `MsgBox Err.Description`

Comment: @SJR - well that is the VB.Net link, here is the VBA one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement, but same thing.

Comment: @BigBen - thanks, must have just seen VB and jumped the gun.

Comment: @SJR than you so much! That did the trick. I really should have seen this myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem here, is the presence of an `On Error` statement inside the error-handling subroutine: when that code runs, it's too late to tell VBA what to do "on error": it's here *because* there was an error.

Just remove the `On Error Resume Next` line, and you're good to go!

---

> *However, if I remove the On Error GoTo ErrorHandler, the description and error number is shown as expected.*

What you're seeing is an unhandled runtime error, not the `MsgBox` you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem. In case I have a larger error handling routine, I assume I can just put the On Error Resume Next after the message box? I had cases where an error occurred in the handler - which led to an infinite loop.

Comment: @MichaelWycisk keep in mind that VBA is either "running normally" or "handling an error". If it's "handling an error" and it didn't `Resume` anywhere, then it's still "handling an error" and any further runtime error will thus be unhandled - you should `Resume` to a subroutine that does the work that can throw more errors, so that you're not trying to direct error-handling control flow while you're in an error handler (note: goto-jumping instead of `Resume` will keep you in "handling an error" mode; you don't want that).